# Modal Bootstrap 4 doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a button to open a Bootstrap 4 modal.

Here's the html:

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#editModal"
  id="btn-modal"
>
  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</button>
```

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="editModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="editModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form method="post" action="xx">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          //Modal Body
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="fas fa-times" style="margin-right:5px"></i> Cancel
          </button>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fas fa-location-arrow " style="margin-right:5px"></i> Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$('#btn-modal').on('click', function(){    
    $("#editModal").modal('show');  
});
```

I've added `console.log("clicked")` in js function and it's shown in console. But still, the modal doesn't show. Can somebody show me the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: No need of `js`here. Its [working](https://www.codeply.com/go/meexgu8wEX) fine

Comment: May be you didn't include your js file

Comment: @User863 thank you. i have deleted the js, but it still doesn't show :( perhaps, is there something else that should check?

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist i did include it, i just didn't post it

Comment: @R.Amalia check Yasser Mas's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are importing all js files near the end of your pages, right before the closing `</body>` tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins, besides no need for js code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

please check the below link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. At most, remove the JS which is unnecessary.

[This is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3rs2hwn/) with your own code, minus the JS and it works just fine!

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>Open</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form method="post" action="xx">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          //Modal Body
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times" style="margin-right:5px"></i> Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow " style="margin-right:5px"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. i have deleted the js, but it still doesn't show :( perhaps, is there something else that should check?

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole HTML-file. If that doesn't work you might have JavaScript switched of in your browser?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" id="btn-modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i
            class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>Open</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form method="post" action="xx">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        //Modal Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"
                                style="margin-right:5px"></i> Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow "
                                style="margin-right:5px"></i> Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```